# Tool for text classification

Tags: data-mining, document-classification

I am interested in learning about text classification so is reading up on the theory. Next step is doing stuff and therefore I am looking for and at different tools. Some links point to [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), however [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/index.php) seems to be a better fit for this task but nobody links to this tool. Are there any reason to stay away from Mallet if wanting to work on a "serious" project ? I was able to quickly train some classifiers with Mallet and test them, whereas with WEKA I run into a problem with my labels "disappearing" after using filters to transform my textfiles in maps named with the category of the texts within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the task you are performing. Mallet is also a popularly used tool and both Weka and Mallet have their pros and cons.
For trivial tasks, both are easy to use. I generaly prefer Weka for clustering and classification tasks.

Note: Do not be misled by popularity of Weka on forum posts, it is primarily to do with it being used for a longer period of time and Mallet is new as compared to Weka.

Comment: I have a corpus with approximately 150.000 terms and trying to do training with a Naive Bayes classifier on my 2GB machine results in an out-of-memory error when using Weka. Using Mallet everything works and the training is done surprisingly quickly. With neither tool has any dimensionality reduction been  done explicitly. So either Mallet is significantly more efficient in its representation for this task compared to Wekas arff file format, or I am not doing things correctly. I am, however, following the Mallet and Weka instructions closely.